# jQuery: Find previous element with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a really simple problem.

How can I find the first previous element of another element? I tried the code below without success.

HTML:

```
<div class = "A">HERE</div>

<div class="B">
    <div class="C" style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#000000;"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.C').click(function() {

        alert($(this).closest('.A').html());

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mcujp/4/

Comment: try `prev('.A')` or `prevAll('.A')`

Comment: Both does not work. Check the fiddle.

Comment: If you look at the jQuery doco, you'll see that `.closest()` only returns an ancestor element (or nothing), not the sibling of an ancestor. Similarly `.prev()` only returns the previous sibling, it doesn't search up through the source looking for a matching element.

Comment: Thanks nnnnnn. That's why it was not working properly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are trying to get the preceding sibling, use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

If you are trying to get the sibling of the parent (like in your example) use `.parent().prev()`.

Comment: `.prev()` only matches siblings. Since `<div class="A">` is not a sibling of `<div class="C">` it will not be matched.

Comment: So finding element in a DOM using jquery is really a case by case scenario? You really have to check how structured your html is.

Comment: That is true when you are trying to find an element based on its proximity to another element. If proximity is not an issue, the structure does not matter greatly because you can use a selector such as `$('.A')` to match the element.

Comment: Thanks George! Make sense!

Comment: A combination of .closest() and .find() is pretty flexible for different html structures as long as the two elements you care about are related through a common ancestor container.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
$('.C').click(function() {

        alert($(this).parent().prev('.A').html());

});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.C').click(function() {
   alert($(this).closest('.B').prev('.A').html());
});
```

Comment: I meant to copy over the first one, looks like I copied after it. Thanks.

Comment: Why $(this).closest('.B').prev('.A').html() works but not only: $(this).closest('.A').html() ?

Comment: $.closest() looks at the current element and its ancestors, and finds the first element that matches your selector. $('.a') is not an ancestor of $('.C'), so $(this).closest('.A') will not select it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to target closest children of top parent you can do so as something define below.

lets assume you have an HTML like

```
<div class="top-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <button class="add-button">Child of 1st Parent DIV</button>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <button class="add-button">Child of 2nd Parent DIV</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).on('click','.add-button',function(){
   $(this).parents('.parent').prev().closest('.parent').find('.add-button').text('im clicked by one of the button next to my parent')
   $(this).parents('.parent').remove();
})
</script>
```

similarly if you want to target grandparent next parent containers children just change `.prev()` to `.next()`

hope i made it simple to define :)